# Webpack - Module build failed: SyntaxError

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Пытаюсь создать React приложение по [туториалу](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html).
**app/main.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
  }
};
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:\app\main.jsx: Unexpected token (6:2)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: package.json в пост закинь через правку

Comment: А где его взять?

Comment: Эм, тогда структуру папок скинь, и как ты запускаешь приложение

Comment: Запускаю через консольку командой webpack-dev-server
Папки такие: 
Корень http://joxi.ru/EA4X0LaCMe6WAb
App http://joxi.ru/n2YZpgYcygQ3A6

Comment: Я не понял, почему ты вызываешь `weback-dev-server`, когда в доке написана команда `webpack`. НО, я когда изучал вхождение в `react`, долго искал хорошие мануалы, нашел только 1 - https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/redux-course-ru/content/chapter1.html, который реально открыл мне свет на происходящее. Сделай все по нему, т.к. там архитектурно правильное создание приложения идет, через `npm` и сборщиков. Все достаточно просто для новичка. Как ни странно офф доки изменились с момента моего изучения, в худшую сторону, начало всегда шло с инициализации `npm`

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что ваш туториал безнадежно протух. А проблема заключается в том, что Babel с версии 6.х требует указания плагинов-трансформаторов кода (*presets*) в явном виде. Однако, при указании загрузчика (*loader*) для webpack вы эти плагины не указываете. Как следствие никакой трансоформации `jsx -> js` по факту не происходит. Отсюда и ругань на неопознанный токен.

Решение тривиально: вместо строки

```
loader: 'babel-loader'
```

вам нужно указать:

```
loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
```

А еще стоит установить пакеты `babel-preset-es2015` и `babel-preset-react`, если они у вас до сих пор не установлены.